# .htaccess: RedirectMatch with RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect every request with a specific keyword in the URI by just replacing this single keyword with another one and leaving the rest as it is on an Apache webserver.

But there is one exception from this behaviour:
If another keyword is, in addition to the first keyword, part of the URI, this redirect should **not** be used.

Example:

```
https://www.domain.tld/projects/myFirstProject
```

should be redirected to

```
https://www.domain.tld/references/myFirstProject
```

but if the keyword "projects" appears to be in a subdirectory of "category", the request should not be redirected:

```
https://www.domain.tld/category/projects
```

Here is what I got for the RewriteMatch, which works for the redirect but can't handle the exception with "category":

```
RedirectMatch 301 /projects(.*) /references$1
```

Note: Parts of the URI other than the keywords being replaced should not be changed!

How can I add a correct RewriteCond? Do I have to rewrite the RedirectMatch with a RewriteCond, RewriteRule solution? How would this solution look like?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you only want to redirect is the URL starts with `projects` you could do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^projects(/.+|$) /references$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Demos:

- http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=1e3b8434-52bd-56ee-8a69-cec35594e232
- http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=1ae94afe-51ad-5e3f-8bdf-fd93d4103156

**EDIT**

Or, if you want to have this work anywhere UNLESS `category` appears *before* `projects` in the URL you could do it like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !category/(.*)projects
RewriteRule (^|/)projects(/.+|$) /references$2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

The `RewriteCond` ensures that the `RewriteRule` is only applied if the URL does not contain `category` followed by `projects`.

- http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=988eadbc-d759-5223-ab5b-00b1a666fb81
- http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=15c90846-9d10-5893-a665-06c9139099cd